# Dynamically call user defined conversion operator in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to dynamically call user defined conversion operators to convert a value to a type?

The method below achieves it by using Expressions, but this is unavailable on platforms which do not support dynamic compilation, like iOS:

```
static object Cast(object obj, Type t)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(obj.GetType());
    return Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(param, t), param).Compile().DynamicInvoke(obj);
}
```

Is there a way that would work without generating code?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "covert"? Casting, calling `Convert.ChangeType`, using custom type mapping function?

Comment: @Amadare42 `Expression.Convert` is cast. OP needs to call cast to invoke user defined conversion operator on some type (i.e. `operator  explicit...`).

Comment: @Amadare42 I want to dynamically call user defined conversion operator, as per the first sentence of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using reflection:

```
var names = new[] {"op_Explicit", "op_Implicit"};
var explicitConversion = obj.GetType()
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(mi => names.Contains(mi.Name) && mi.ReturnType == t) 
    .FirstOrDefault();
return explicitConversion == null
    ? Convert.ChangeType(obj, t)
    : explicitConversion.Invoke(null, new[]{ obj });
```

Comment: Unfortunately Convert.ChangeType only deals with types implemting IConvertible. It does not call user defined conversion operators.

Comment: @kaalus please see update. As far as i understand this portion of reflection should be available on iOS.